# How to do .attr or similar using javascript without using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr

```
$("#my_iframe").attr("src","www.examples.com?x=asd&y=qwe");
```

This is done using jquery while I have to perform this operation without jquery. How to implement this with javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('my_iframe').src = 'www.examples.com?x=asd&y=awe';
```

The DOM API provided by the browser gives you things that look like objects with ordinary properties. They're *not* "ordinary" properties, of course, because magic things happen when you set them (well some of them).

With "modern" versions of jQuery, in a situation like this it's (a little bit) better to use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("my_iframe").src = "www.examples.com?x=asd&y=awe";
```

or

```
document.getElementById("my_iframe").setAttribute("src","www.examples.com?x=asd&y=awe");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `setAttribute()` method to set particular attribute on particular element. like

```
document.getElementById('my_iframe').setAttribute('src',  'www.examples.com?x=asd&y=awe');
```